# Why query column return zeros when connect with ODBC connection to MS SQL?

Tags: php, sql-server

I want get values from the cloud server on which MSSQL is running. I use ODBC connection in php to get data. But numeric field called **Balance** in cloud return zero values in myside which have non zero values. I have check the the datatype which return from cloud, and it is float.here is my code to fetch data.

```
<?php 
   $select_Total_Outstanding = "Select CustCode,CustName,Balance FROM AS_vwCustomer";
   $result = odbc_exec($conn1, $select_Total_Outstanding);
 ?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>CustCode</th>
        <th>CustName</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
    </tr>
<?php
    while (odbc_fetch_row($result)) {
        echo '<tr>';       
        $field1 = odbc_result($result,1);
        $field2 = odbc_result($result,2);
        $field3 = odbc_result($result,3);
        echo '<td>'.$field1.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$field2.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$field3.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
   }

?>
</table>
```

AS_vwCustomer is a view created in the cloud server and I have observe the AS_somethingelse has a numeric field which return non zero values on myside successfully.Currently I have no access to the query of the view created and i think there is something wrong with the AS_vwCustomer **Balance** field.

Is there any other way to get values of that field?

Comment: please post your connection code

Comment: @Fahrudin  I have use `odbc_connect($serverName, $user_name, $PWD)` as my connection code and **$serverName** include the datasource(host name and port,database name).My connection is OK and i'm getting the integer and string data as expected.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details. Float data type can also store a 0. What is the problem here?

Comment: Cloud Server have data(not zeros) like 213.89. But it return as zeros.Could you help me @Alex?

Comment: Edit your question and add query/SP code that gets executed and PHP code that consumes the results.